# 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' after second request

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I made a web server that serves as a client-side using socket.io-client and express (because I have to use this form in other project).

It emits the string posted and when receiving 'boom' emit from io server it responds by sending the string served.

Posting 'heat_bomb' works well for the first time, but when I try second time '[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' occurs at res.send(data) in socket.on().

Is there a way to refresh whenever post request is generated, so that each request uses independent response?

app.ts

```
import express from 'express'
import {io} from 'socket.io-client'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'

const app=express()
const PORT=8080

const socket=io(`http://localhost:2002`, {
    query:{
        hello:"merhaba"
    }
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname+`/index.html`)
})
app.post('/heat_bomb', (req, res)=>{
    socket.emit('heat_bomb', req.body.elem)
    socket.on('boom', (data)=>{
        res.send(data)
    })
})

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server Running: ${PORT}`)
})
```

index.html

```
$('#heat_button').click(function(){
    console.log('heating bomb')
    $.post('/heat_bomb', {elem: $('#input_number').val()},(data, status)=>{
        console.log(data)
        console.log('heated')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/heat_bomb` middleware registers a new `boom` handler for every request on the same globally defined `socket`. Although your code snippet does not show how the `heat_bomb` and `boom` events are connected, I assume that the `emit('boom')` during the second request re-triggers the `heat_bomb` handler that was registered during the first request, leading to another `res.send` for the `res` from the first request, which is already completed. This leads to the observed error message.

`socket.once('boom')` alone will not solve this reliably: if one `heat_bomb` event can overtake another, the `data` from the first can wrongly be "paired" with the `res` from the second. The `res` needs to be a second argument of your events, something like this:

```js
socket.emit('heat_bomb', req.body.elem, res);
socket.once('boom', function(data, res) {
  res.send(data);
});
```

Comment: Since I was using socket.on, the same handler keeped regustering again. I changed `socket.on('boom')` to `socket.once('boom')` so that the handler is removed right after it was called. It works!

Comment: @JonghyunPark, not sure whether this is a reliable solution, see my edited answer.